# How do I specify an option can be both a number or string?

Tags: node.js, yargs

I am trying to set up an option that is both `type: "number"` and `type: "string"`.

[The documentation for `.option()`](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/api.md#optionkey-opt) specifies that the `type` property of the option options object should be a string, and two of those choices are number and string. However, I want it to accept *both*.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your title and first sentence of the question don't say the same thing.  Please fix one of them.  And, since something can't be two types at once, do you mean something that can be a number OR a string?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes...